# Construct and graph a function that is from [-4,2] because of algebraic concerns.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider this a square root only works if the input is negative. Can you put something under a square root that is not negative from -4,2 but negative everywhere else?

How do I create a problem that fits this criterion?

Comment: Think of a quadratic that satisfies this.

Comment: You mean like $9-(x+1)^2$, which is $-(x+4)(x-2)$?

Comment: I would have to graph

Comment: A real square root exists only if the radicand is *non*-negative

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use the fact that $-(x-a)(x-b)$ is negative everywhere except in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Consider also $3 - |x+1|$. This is really $3 - |x - (-1)|$, where $-1$ is the midpoint of $-4$ and $2$, and $3$ is the "radius".

Comment: So are you wondering whether you can have a function like $\sqrt{-(x+4)(x-2)}$ or $\sqrt{3-|x+1|}$? These are defined for $-4 \le x \le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question one can begin by doing the following. Taking consideration into what you said my approach would go as follows:

I would first write the following:

## Quadratic Equation

$$-(x+4)(x-2)=0$$
The zeros of this function are the end points of your interval which is $[-4,2]$.

This function is positive everywhere but $(-\infty,-4]$ and $[2,+\infty)$

[image: Graph of Quadratic Equation]

## Square Root Equation

Now to do what you desire which is to have a square root function of that function I would do the following:

$$f(x)=-(x+4)(x-2)$$
$$g(x)=\sqrt{x}$$
$$(g\circ f)(x)=\sqrt{-(x+4)(x-2)}$$

This function looks as follows:

[image: Square Root Graph]